# Proof $p(x),p'(x), p''(x),p'''(x)$ from a basis por polynomials of degree three

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I need to proof that given a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree three, the set $\left\{p(x),p'(x), p''(x),p'''(x)\right\}$ from a basis. Let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$, with $a_3\neq 0$. I calculated the derivatives

$p'(x)= a_1+2a_2x+3a_2x^2$,

$p''(x)=2a_2+6a_3x$, and

$p'''(x)=6a_3$.

This set will be a basis if this system has a solution

$\left( \begin{matrix} 
a_0 & a_1 & 2a_2 & 6a_3 \\
a_1 & 2a_2 & 6a_3 & 0 \\
a_2 & 3a_3 & 0 & 0 \\
a_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{matrix} \right|\left.  \begin{matrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\ a_3 \end{matrix}\right)$

And that's true because the determinant of this matrix is $103a_3^4$, i.e, is different of zero since $a_3\neq 0$.

That's correct?

Comment: Correction: form a basis, and the determinant is $108a_3^4$

Comment: @Matech I think the sign is minus...

Comment: something needs to be said about the field characteristic.  e.g. $p(x):=x^3\in \mathbb F_3[x]$ is problematic for building a basis with derivatives

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct.

Another possible approach would be using the fact that polynomials of different degrees are always linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ for the last column, since you want to show that $A$ is invertible; you need that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for *any* $b$.

And to make the determinant easier, you may switch the rows.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need matrices to note$$\begin{align}6a_3&=p^{\prime\prime\prime},\\6a_3x&=p^{\prime\prime}-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime},\\3a_2x^2&=p^\prime-\frac{a_1}{6a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime}-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}(p^{\prime\prime}-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime}),\\a_3x^3&=p-\frac{a_0}{6a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime}-\frac{a_1}{6a_3}(p^{\prime\prime}-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime})-\frac13\left(p^\prime-\frac{a_1}{6a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime}-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}(p^{\prime\prime}-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}p^{\prime\prime\prime})\right).\end{align}$$